# Silverlight 4 RIA Services, the SIlverlight 4 Toolkit controls and many to many relationships in database

Tags: c#, .net, many-to-many, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-toolkit

I was looking at snippets and tutorials for quite some time now, but I can't find a complete answer - just some bits and pieces.

I have a database with 3 tables:

Product:

- **id** uniqueidentifier
- **name** nvarchar(50)

Category:

- **id** uniqueidentifier
- **name** nvarchar(50)

ProductCategory:

- **fk_product** uniqueidentifier
- **fk_category** uniqueidentifier

Obviously there is a many-to-many relationship involved - a product can have multiple categories and a category can be applied to multiple products.

The next step was to generate ADO.NET Model and the domain service from the database. This is pretty much simple and I think standard.

Now in the view I make use of DataGrid and DataForm provided by the Silverlight 4 Toolkit.

```
<toolkit:DataForm ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=ProductsSource}" Name="dataForm1" AutoCommit="True" />
```

and

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGird" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=ProductsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

The data source ProductsSource is defined as such:

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource Name="ProductsSource" QueryName="GetProductsQuery" AutoLoad="True">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
            <riaControls:SortDescriptor Direction="Ascending" PropertyPath="title" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <domain:PortfolioDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Now: What is the best way to present the data from this many-to-many relationship in the view? Is there a way to show a multiselect-enabled listbox inside the DataForm for a property which has an many-to-many relationship associated with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768489/many-to-many-relationship-in-net-ria-services)

Apparently Many-to-many (where the EF model removes the association table) is not support in RIA services.

You need to include the association table. I think an association table is only included in an EF model if it contains any extra fields (additional to the 2 foreign keys), or of you break one of the associations and manage one side of the many-to-many relationship yourself.