# C# How to handle Navigation properties in n:m association in RIA Domain Service?

Tags: c#, silverlight, associations, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

Within a Silverlight5 / RIA Services application I built a Domain Service on a very simple database:

Booking n:1 Equipment 1:n GroupToEquipment n:1 Group

In my auto-generated edmx the GroupToEquipment entity never shows up and a n:m association directly from Equipment to Group is shown. So far so good.

To have the reference from the Equipment to the 1:n associated bookings within my DomainService, I had to insert [Include] and [Association...] within the "DomainService.metadata.cs"

```
[Include]
[Association("FK_Booking_Equipment", "EquipmentId","EquipmentId")]
public EntityCollection<Booking> Booking { get; set; }
```

and added an .Include("Booking") within the "DomainService.cs"

```
public IQueryable<Equipment> GetEquipment()
{
   return this.ObjectContext.Equipment.Include("Booking");
}
```

This works perfect and the references to all the bookings are loaded when querying the Equipment! BUT how do I have to adopt this for the n:m Group-association??

The following code is what I then additionally tried within the "DomainService.metadata.cs":

```
    internal sealed class EquipmentMetadata
    {

        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private EquipmentMetadata()
        {
        }

        [Include]
        [Association("FK_Booking_Equipment", "EquipmentId","EquipmentId")]
        public EntityCollection<Booking> Booking { get; set; }

        public Guid EquipmentId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("GroupToEquipment", "EquipmentId", "GroupId")]
        public EntityCollection<Group> Group { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this in the DomainService:

```
    public IQueryable<Equipment> GetEquipment()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Equipment.Include("Booking").Include("Group");
    }
```

The code compiles fine but there are NO references to the Groups after querying the Equipment.... :-(

What am I doing wrong? Pretty sure this is only a small issue for someone who knows...

best regards,
Flo.

Comment: Did you get back references to Bookings? I'd try two things: 1) Run Fiddler2 and look at what's returned under WCF Silverlight 2) Remove the [Association] - I never had to include it

Comment: Booking references are included. If I remove [Association] the compilation fails....

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but WCF Ria doesn't supports m:n relationship! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768528/363198) Nikhil kotary answer from more info

I suggest you to create an m:n class and handle the relationship manually, in other words you must expose the GroupToEquipment entity from db to edmx and from edmx to WCF Ria.

If can't stand with this option, and prefer to add a dependency on other code, have a look at [m2mria on codeplex](http://m2m4ria.codeplex.com), I've tried it on really basic scenario and it worked

Hope this helps,
Marco

Comment: thanks for the information.
in the meantime I made my desired enhancements on the server-side of the solution and send the filtered result-set via the Domain Service.